# How to save a value to a variable of a function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

This Code uses the Nativescript Plugin

```
let power = require("nativescript-powerinfo");

power.startPowerUpdates(function (Info) {
    console.log("battery charge: " + Info.percent + "%");
});
```

> Console Log: battery charge: 100 %

I would like to save this Info.percent to a variable so I can later on reuse it.

Unlucky it always says, that its undefined. I tried different approaches.

Like:

```
var batterystatus = power.startPowerUpdates(function(Info){
      return Info.percent;
}
```

or

```
power.startPowerUpdates(function(Info){
          return Info.percent;

var batterystatus = power.startPowerUpdates(function);
```

or I also tried:

```
var batterystatus = power.startPowerUpdates(function(Info){
          this.batterystatus = Info.percent
}
```

But all pretty much deliver the wrong result.

> typeof(Info.percent) = number

Comment: `startPowerUpdates(...)` is a callback executes on its own context. The last option would work but you have to retain the context, you may use an arrow function to do so. Also make sure you run it inside NgZone. If you are new to JavaScript / TypeScript, I would recommend you to get through the basics first.

Comment: Sidenote: there is a typo, `this.battterystatus = Info.percent` with three "t". Not necessarily related to the main issue.

Comment: I don't understand why the down votes, this is a perfectly acceptable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method startPowerUpdates will call the function that you are passing to it, but it seems that startPowerUpdates doesn't return the same returned value. Either the function is called asynchronously or it simply wasn't programmed for it to return the same value. Try this instead:

```
let power = require("nativescript-powerinfo");

let batteryPercent;

power.startPowerUpdates(function (Info) {
    batteryPercent = Info.percent;
    console.log("battery charge: " + batteryPercent + "%");
});
```

Then check afterward if `batteryPercent` is set. If it is not then the function is being called in parallel and you'll have to code a trigger to let the program know that the value has been set. Example:

First check if the function is called synchronously (probably not):

```
...

console.log(batteryPercent); // check the value here
```

If the console log is undefined, then you'll need another approach:

```
let updateBatteryPercent = (newBatteryPercent) => {
    batteryPercent = newBatteryPercent;
    continueExecutionFunction();
}

// and now you should have:
power.startPowerUpdates(function (Info) {
    console.log("battery charge: " + Info.percent+ "%");
    updateBatteryPercent(Info.percent);
});

function continueExecutionFunction() {
    // here you should have whatever you'd like to
    // happen after you find out the battery percent
}
```

Ideally, you should use await and async functions, but that's more advanced. Don't play with them until problems like the one you had are easy.

Comment: wow great! sometimes the first call is undefined but afterwards it seems to work perfectly! thanks a lot!

Comment: I did but due to my low  repuation (12) below 15 the score isnt showed public yet. but i guess it will soon :)

Comment: @sensenmann You just magically earned reputation (lol wasn't me ;) ). Try again. By the way, I've noticed that you've been answering a couple of questions recently. I recommend you to give a few high quality answers over many low quality.